# $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{n} (1+\frac{x^2}{n})^n e^{-2x^2-\frac{1}{n}} dx$

Tags: integration, limits, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have to calculate the following limit:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{n} (1+\frac{x^2}{n})^n e^{-2x^2-\frac{1}{n}} dx$

---

I would like to try using the Dominated Convergence Thm.

First of all, I tried to calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{x^2}{n})^n e^{-2x^2-\frac{1}{n}}=e^{-2x^2}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{x^2}{n})^n e^{-\frac{1}{n}}$

But I don't know how to continue... Am I doing it ok? Or how can I do it?

Comment: $\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^n \to e^{x^2}$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: So $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)=e^{-x^2} $ ??? @lc2r43

Comment: @User160 Precisely, and you should know how to dominate $e^{-x^2}$ on any interval $[0,n]$

Comment: So I have to integrate $f(x)=e^-x^2$ no? I mean, do I have to calculate $\int_0^n e^{-x^2}dx$ ? I don't know how to calculate this integral @DavideTrono

Comment: @User160 You need to calculate that integral up to $\infty$ and not just $n$, since you sent $n$ to $\infty$ already.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the sequence of functions
$$f_n(x)=\bigg(1+\dfrac{x^2}{n}\bigg)^ne^{-(2x^2+1/n)}\chi_{[0,n]}\ge 0.$$ in order to study the integral from $0$ to $+\infty$.
Fix $x\in(0,+\infty)\implies f_n(x)\to e^{x^2}\cdot e^{-2x^2}=\dfrac{1}{e^{x^2}}=:f(x)$ surely almost everywhere in $[0,+\infty)$. Then observe that ($n$ is fixed now)
$$f_n(x)\overset{n_0\in\mathbb N}{\longrightarrow}\begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{e^{n_0}}&&x\in\mathcal U(0^+)\\ \dfrac{c}{e^{x^2}}&&x\in\mathcal U(+\infty) \end{cases}$$
so we can state that it exists a positive function $g(x)\in \mathcal L^1(\mathbb R^+)$ such that
$$|f_n(x)|\le g(x)=\begin{cases}1&&x\in[0,1)\\\dfrac{c}{e^{x^2}}&&x\in[1,+\infty) \end{cases}\implies$$
$$\lim_n\int_0^{+\infty}\dfrac{\big(1+\frac{x^2}{n}\big)^n}{e^{(2x^2+1/n)}}\chi_{[0,n]}dx=\int_0^{+\infty}f(x)dx.$$
The primitive of the function $e^{-x^2}$ is not easy to calculate, but maybe you've seen that $\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}dx=\dfrac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$. (?)

Comment: One can also use $$\left( {1 + \frac{{x^2 }}{n}} \right)^n  = \exp \left( {n\log \left( {1 + \frac{{x^2 }}{n}} \right)} \right) \le \exp \left( {n\frac{{x^2 }}{n}} \right) = e^{x^2 } 
$$ and $e^{ - 1/n}  \le 1$. I think in your $g(x)$, $2x^2$ should be $x^2$.